# ZFS mount dataset for zone

Tags: solaris, pool, zfs

I shutdown my non-global zone and umount her point zfs zonepath.

command for umount:

```
zfs unmount -f zones-pool/one-zone
```

details:

```
zfs list | grep one
zones-pool/one-zone                                  15,2G  9,82G    32K  /zones-fs/one-zone
zones-pool/one/rpool/ROOT/solaris               15,2G  9,82G  7,83G  /zones-fs/one/root
```

in the above, it is seen that there is an occupied space, 9.82G of 15.2G

more details:

```
# zfs get mountpoint zones-pool/one-zone
NAME                       PROPERTY    VALUE                      SOURCE
zones-pool/one-zone        mountpoint  /zones-fs/one-zone          local


# zfs get mounted zones-pool/one-zone
NAME                       PROPERTY  VALUE  SOURCE
zones-pool/one-zone         mounted   no     -
```

but, if I try mount point zfs

I can not see the content

step 1 mount:

```
zfs mount zones-pool/one-zone
```

step 2 see mount with df -h:

```
 df -h | grep one
zones-pool/one-zone/rpool/ROOT/solaris    25G    32K       9,8G     1%    /zones-fs/one-zone/root
zones-pool/one-zone    25G    32K       9,8G     1%    /zones-fs/one-zone
```

step 3 list content:

```
ls -l /zones-fs/one-zone/root
total 0
```

why?

also in step 2, you see that df -h prints 1% used

I do not understand

Comment: [`df(1)`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/df.html#tag_20_33_10) has a field order of "name", "size", "used", "available", "capacity", and "mount-point".  So it is showing that the working version of each data-set is only using 32K, so they are probably empty.  You can try checking for snapshots in the root data-set since it refers to ~8G: `ls /zone-fs/one-zone/root/.zfs/snapshot/`

Comment: Yes, it seems to be empty. But it was not empty and just i unmounted zfs.

Comment: And now my zone does not start up

Comment: `zfl list` says that the data-set is referring to 7,83G of data, and that includes snapshots & clones.  `df` does not include snapshots/clones in its calculations and only shows 32K, likely the minimum size.  So some version of your data should be there, but my understanding is limited beyond that.

Answer (score 0):

To view contents of zoned dataset you need to start zone or mount it directly.

Zone files (root-fs) are located into dataset

```
zones-pool/one-zone/rpool/ROOT/solaris
```

To mount it you need to change its "zoned" option to off and set "mountpoint" option to path you want to mount.
This may be done via

```
zfs set zoned=off zones-pool/one-zone/rpool/ROOT/solaris
zfs set mountpoint=/zones-pool/one-zone-root-fs
```

Space into dataset may be occupied by snapshots and clones, you may check them by commands:

```
zfs list -t snap zones-pool
zfs get -H -r -o value,name origin dom168vol1 | grep -v '^-'
```

The first command displays all snapshots, the second command displays datasets which are depends from some snapshots (have not "-" origin property).